# ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wonder how come this error is thrown while hosting my project in APP ENGINE, I have added lots of logging just for analysis sake. When I use the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver using ip from my local it works. Kindly help !!

```
    String name = "Vinodh";
    String url = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
        url = "jdbc:google:mysql://xxxxxxx:xxxxxx/vinodh?user=root&password=xxxxxx";

        // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
        log.info("Initiate Connection");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        log.info("Got Connection");
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
        // Result set get the result of the SQL query
        ResultSet resultSet = statement

                .executeQuery("select * from Family");
        log.info("Entering While");
        while(resultSet.next()){
             log.info("Entered While");
            String test = resultSet.getString("Name");
            System.out.println(test);

            name = test+test+test;
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to MySQL or Workbench itself?

Answer (score 2):

As shwown in this tutorial, during development you should use the normal mysql driver and only appengine use the Google mysql driver

```
  if (SystemProperty.environment.value() ==
      SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production) {
    // Load the class that provides the new "jdbc:google:mysql://" prefix.
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
    url = "jdbc:google:mysql://your-project-id:your-instance-name/guestbook?user=root";
  } else {
    // Local MySQL instance to use during development.
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/guestbook?user=root";
  }
```

Also double check that you have enabled **MySQL Connector/J** for your application (it's not done by default)

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/#enable_connector_j

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
  ...
  <use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
</appengine-web-app>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. As you see this is the first time I'm trying to deploy using MySQl.Currently I'm getting the below error,

Comment: com.connecttest.Connector2Servlet doGet: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Found it from stack overflow :-). root musnt use password. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm currently getting this exception ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37644148/java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-load-jdbc-driver-class-com-mysql-jdb)) but in my case I am going from Google Flexible to Cloud SQL. Do I have to specify `use-google-connector-j` somewhere too?

Answer (score 1):

Appearently they removed this quietly. It's not even in the docs of `appengine-web.xml` anymore.

Use the standard `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` but update your JDBC url for:

```
jdbc:mysql://google/[your-db-schema]
   ?user=root
   &password=[your-db-passord]
   &socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
   &cloudSqlInstance=[your-db-project-id]:[your-db-region]:[your-db-intance]
```

Add also to your gradle:

```
dependencies {
   ...
   implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.29")
   implementation("com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.5.0")
}
```

Note the "google" in the URI. There's no place in the docs saying that you need it, but you have to.

[Github official page guide](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc-mysql.md)

Answer (score 0):

**My App Engine Java 11 2023 solution**

I started from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72073928/3979415) and follow this documentation: [docs](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory/blob/main/docs/jdbc.md)

First add dependency on gradle:

```
implementation('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33')
implementation('com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.11.0')
```

Then you can connect to Cloud SQL in this way:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); //com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver is deprecated

String jdbcUrl = "jdbc:mysql:///<DATABASE_NAME>?" 
               + "cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>" 
               + "&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory" 
               + "&user=<MYSQL_USER_NAME>" 
               + "&password=<MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>";

//now can use your connection string..for example:
DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, <MYSQL_USER_NAME>, <MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD>)
```

**cloudSqlInstance** is The instance connection name (found on the instance details page). It's something like project_id:cloud_sql_zone:cloud_sql_name