# com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am deploying my project on Google app engine and this project also has a SQL instance.

However, when I try to run the code I get ClassNotFoundException when I try to load the class like

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
```

I followed all the documentation given here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/cloud-sql/

and also looked at this solution

[ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20173043/classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-googledriver)

my appengine-web.xml has the entry -

```
<use-google-connector-j>true</use-google-connector-j>
```

Any idea where I could be going wrong?

Comment: Hi Prabhjot.
I've just successfully deployed and run cloudsql sample [1] and it works fine. You just need to define application and version as here [2]. Try to spot the differences between your code and [1].
Cheers!

[1] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/cloudsql
[2] https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/helloworld/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml